# Determine if the integer is one digit and add a zero before it

Tags: string, swift, int

I need to check if the int is only one digit and if it is, I want to add a zero in front of it. I  have this code but it doesnt work.

```
var minutes2 = Int(minutes)
var minutessize: Int = sizeofValue(minutes2)

if minutessize < 2 {
    var needStringHere = "0\(minutes2)"
    let a: Int? = needStringHere.toInt()
    minutes2 = a!
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just check if the minutes count is less than 10:

```
var str = "\(minutes2)"
if (minutes2 < 10) { str = "0\(minutes2)" }
```

Comment: yea but how do i convert the string to an int. The code doesnt work there

Comment: @DenizYazar `var integer = Int(str)`